# Rotate a rectangle consisting of 4 tuples to left or right

Tags: python, python-3.x, rotation, gis

I'm working on a program to manipulate GIS data, but for this precise problem, I'm trying to rotate a rectangle of 4 points around the bottom left corner. I've got 1 tuple describing the bottom left corner:
 `x, y=40000,40000`
I've also got a length x, and a length y, `x_displacement`, and `y_displacement`. I've got an angle, `theta`, in degrees. I want to rotate the rectangle by up to 90 degrees left or right, so theta can be -89 to 89 degrees. Negative angles should rotate the corners to the left; positive angles to the right.I've represented the rectangle as such: 
http://i.imgur.com/pp3hFyA.jpg

```
    x_displacement=100
    y_displacement=100
    x = 40000
    y = 40000
    x1 = x
    y1 = y + a.y_displacement
    x2 = x + a.x_displacement
    y2 = y + a.y_displacement
    x3 = x + a.x_displacement
    y3 = y
    #describes the other 4 corners of the rectangle
```

Coord is a class that holds an x and a y value. `coords` is a list of Coord class items.

```
    c = Coord(x, y)
    coords.append(c)
    c = Coord(x1, y1)
    coords.append(c)
    c = Coord(x2, y2)
    coords.append(c)
    c = Coord(x3, y3)
    coords.append(c)
    #Adds each corner to the list of coordinates
    theta = math.radians(a.angle)
    newcoords = []
    for c in coords:
        newcoords.append(Coord((c.x * math.cos(theta) - c.y * math.sin(theta)),
                              (c.x * math.sin(theta) + c.y * math.cos(theta))))
    coords=newcoords
```

I suspect that there's something relatively trivial that I'm doing wrong, but I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time.
This code produces a new rectangle that is either misshapen, or has negative corners, rather than slightly left-rotated corners as wanted. 
I've seen many posts on here about rotating rectangles, but none seem to be a direct duplicate, because they do not handle negative angles. I'd appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Your logic needs to be relative to the first vertex - yours is relative to world space.  You'll never want to transform the 1st coord

Comment: what is the pivot for the rotation? (the origin, apparently?)

Comment: @njzk2 The pivot is the bottom left corner.

Comment: works from my point of view: https://repl.it/DpHD

Comment: (you need to change coordinates first, if you want to pivot around something that is not the origin)

Comment: @njzk2 try it with negative angles though- I'm pretty sure that's the problem. I suppose I could put in a check for a negative angle, then add 180 degrees? Could you explain the changing coordinates if possible? And thank you, btw, for spending time on this! This site is a godsend.

Comment: seems alright with negative angles too (just reverse the values in the example I sent.) There is a level of imprecision, because `math` uses radians, and integer angles in degrees do not have a finite representation in radians, so you'll have the occasional 0.499999999 instead of 0.5, but otherwise that looks ok.

Comment: I recommend that you write test cases, compute the expected results by hand, and compare the output of your code with what you came up with. If you get discrepancies, add your test data to your question.

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you for all your help. You were spot on about needing to change my axis of rotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a few commenters mentioned, you are rotating around the (0, 0) point, rather than the lower left point. As we are constructing the coordinates we can:

- First construct the shape at the (0, 0) point
- Rotate it
- Translate it out to where it needs to be

The below gives an example using plain lists rather than your Coord object, but I'm sure it makes the point.

```
import math


def rotate(xy, theta):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions
    cos_theta, sin_theta = math.cos(theta), math.sin(theta)

    return (
        xy[0] * cos_theta - xy[1] * sin_theta,
        xy[0] * sin_theta + xy[1] * cos_theta
    )


def translate(xy, offset):
    return xy[0] + offset[0], xy[1] + offset[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the square relative to (0, 0)
    w, h = 100, 100

    points = [
        (0, 0),
        (0, h),
        (w, h),
        (w, 0)
    ]

    offset = (40000, 50000)
    degrees = 90
    theta = math.radians(degrees)

    # Apply rotation, then translation to each point
    print [translate(rotate(xy, theta), offset) for xy in points]
```

As a bonus, this should work with any set of points defined relative to (0, 0), regardless of whether they form any sensible polygon.

Comment: This worked liked a charm after jiggering a bit to fit custom types. Thank you so much! http://prntscr.com/cq8imv